# Passing generic reader to a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method

```
public Customer InitializeCustomer (reader)
{
        Customer customer =new Customer();

        customer.CompanyName = reader[1].ToString();

        customer.Address1 = reader[2].ToString();

        customer.Address2 = reader[3].ToString();

        customer.City = reader[4].ToString();

        customer.State = reader[5].ToString();

        customer.Zip = reader[6].ToString();
}
```

This method will be same. But the problem is the parameter to InitializeCustomer 'reader' will be depend on the type of file I am readin. Some time I have to read data from xls file and some other times CSV etc. I can have a method overload with different reader. But is it possible to have one method which will work for any type of reader like oledbreader, streamreader etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do all of those classes derive from?

Comment: Customer is class defined in the program. No inheritance used.

Comment: What is `reader`'s type?

Comment: Reader type depends on the type of file. If It is an xls file then the reader type oledbreader, if it is csv file then it is streamreader etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the readers you end up using happen to use the indexing operator (the square brackets), then you can just use `dynamic`:

```
public Customer InitializeCustomer (dynamic reader)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    // Automatically calls the [1] indexer for whatever class reader is
    customer.CompanyName = reader[1].ToString();
    // ...

    return Customer;
}
```

P.S. **In the interest of good code structure,** I would recommend to move this method to the `Customer` class, where it belongs. For example:

```
public static Customer FromReader(dynamic reader)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    // Automatically calls the [1] indexer for whatever class reader is
    customer.CompanyName = reader[1].ToString();
    // ...

    return Customer;
}

[...]

var customer = Customer.FromReader(myDbReader);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible, as long as those readers have a common base class or interface.  For instance, a `StringReader` and a `StreamReader` are both `TextReader`s.  So if you only need to use members of `TextReader`, you should make that the type of your parameter.  However, if your different readers expose different interfaces which you need to use differently, you're out of luck and you'll need multiple overloads.  Either that or you'll need to provide some wrappers for readers that are different so that they all present a common interface to your method.  Unfortunately, `StreamReader` and `OleDbReader` have little in common, which is understandable if you look them.